# IServiceProvider with Autofac and webjob

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, azure-webjobs

I'm working in an Azure webJob.
I'm using **autofac** with a `IJobActivator` an everything is ok. 
But now, I need to call code that is using `IServiceProvider` and at that moment I get an error from **Autofac** because `IServiceProvider` is not known.

When I'm using the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection()` to register my Interfaces in place of **Autofac** it is working (*I don't know where the IServiceProvider is registered but it is working*).

The company I work for is asking me to explicitly use **Autofac**.
I struggle to find to way to use **Autofac** but declare the `IServiceProvider` within the WebJob.

Have someone an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to call code that is using IServiceProvider and at that moment I get an error from Autofac because IServiceProvider is not known.
>   Does that mean when running your Webjob, you could not find the IServiceProvider in AutofacActivator. 
>   I am not clear about how do you define IServiceProvider and how do you inject it?

I think you could inject IServiceProvider into job activator and register it then you could use this instance to get service.

You could register the IServiceProvider interface before build in ContainerConfig:

```
public static class ContainerConfig
    {
        public static IContainer GetContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<Functions>();

            builder.RegisterType<HelloGenerator>().As<IStringGenerator>().SingleInstance();
            builder.Register<IServiceProvider>(context =>
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            //todo: register the interfaces
            return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }).SingleInstance();

            return builder.Build();
        }
}
```

Get service when triggered in Functions:

```
public class Functions
    {
        private readonly IStringGenerator _stringGenerator;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        public Functions(IStringGenerator strGenerator,IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
           _stringGenerator = strGenerator;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
        public void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
           log.WriteLine(_stringGenerator.GetWord());
            log.WriteLine(_serviceProvider.GetService(xxxxxx));
        }
    }
```

In Progtam:

```
static void Main()
        {
            var config = new JobHostConfiguration
            {
                JobActivator = new AutofacActivator(ContainerConfig.GetContainer())
            };
            var host = new JobHost(config);

            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
```

In AutofacActivator:

```
public class AutofacActivator : IJobActivator
    {
        private readonly IContainer _container;

        public AutofacActivator(IContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public T CreateInstance<T>()
        {
            return _container.Resolve<T>();
        }
}
```

If this is not what you want, hope you could give me more detailed description and your main idea code.

Answer (score 4):

In fact I solved my issue by using Extensions:

```
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

by using them doing the following:

```
_containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
_containerBuilder.Populate(new ServiceCollection());
_containerBuilder.RegisterType<MyGreatType>().InstancePerDependency();
_container = _containerBuilder.Build();
```

It generates automatically the `IServiceProvider` for you